# Formula including a reference cell

Tags: excel

Example: I need to count the number of values in a range that are greater than 3, but I don't want to have to rewrite the formula every time the criteria number may change.  So the criteria number is calculated in a reference cell. So, lets say, 3 is entered in cell A2.  A formula should be countif(C:C,>A2). Excel does not seem to like the greater than used with a reference cell.  Is there a work around?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,">"&A2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I have very little hair left to pull out.